# Display an image in a Image container in WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I am trying to display an image in an WPF Image container

```
string imageContent = ((DataRowView)dgQuestions.SelectedItem)["QuestionImage"].ToString();
if (imageContent.Length >= 5)
{
    byte[] data = (byte[])((DataRowView)dgQuestions.SelectedItem)["QuestionImage"];
    ImageSourceConverter imgConv = new ImageSourceConverter();
    imageSource = (ImageSource)imgConv.ConvertFromString(data.ToString());
}
```

The last line of the above code generates the following error

> object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm not bothered with how the datagrid displays the image as the user will never see the it.

This is how I am filling the grid:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = Con;
cmd.CommandText = "getQuizQuestions";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@quizid", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = quizId;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter daSubject = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet dsSubject = new DataSet();
daSubject.Fill(dsSubject, "QuizSubject");
dgQuestions.ItemsSource = dsSubject.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

Comment: have you used the debuggger to check if 'data' is null?  And why aren't you using ConvertFromString(imageContent)?

Comment: imageContent contains "System.Byte[]" I am using that to just make sure that there is something to go into data

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint and validate data isn't null. Also, why don't you set the image source as the byte[] instead of using a ToString():

```
public BitmapImage ImageFromBuffer(Byte[] bytes)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
    image.BeginInit();
    image.StreamSource = stream;
    image.EndInit();
    return image;
}

public Byte[] BufferFromImage(BitmapImage imageSource)
{
    Stream stream = imageSource.StreamSource;
    Byte[] buffer = null;
    if (stream != null && stream.Length > 0)
    {
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            buffer = br.ReadBytes((Int32)stream.Length);
        }
    }

    return buffer;
}
```